# regex to get all strings in a sentence, which are of 7 characters and which start with a digit and end with a digit

Tags: regex

I want to extract all strings in a sentence which start with a digit and end with digit, and are of 7 character length. Between the first and last digit, it can contain digits or letters.

Example: Sample text for testing: 0012345 15R7544 35P2699

I want to get these strings- 0012345, 15R7544 , 35P2699

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let patt = /\b\d[\da-zA-Z]{5}\d\b/g;

let str = "hello 35P2699 world another 0012345 random";

console.log(str.match(patt));
```

`\b` is word boundary, checks for the string start and end.

`\d` checks for a digit.

`[\da-zA-Z]{5}` checks for 5 occurrences of a digit or a letter, in between a start and end digit.

Answer (score 0):

In perl, you can place all of them in an array like this

```
 my @strings= $str=~/(\b\d\w{5}\d\b)/g ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regexp. You would need to trim each output.

```
(^|\s)\d{1,1}[\d|\w]{5,5}\d{1,1}($|\s)
```